# How to typecast to datarow from string

Tags: c#, asp.net

> 'cannot implicitly convert type string to data row[]'.

Is it possible to store the string type to data row[]? I need to store the value of the particular column in that particular data row array. Suggest me an answer please.

```
DataRow[] drprocess = objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessName"].ToString();
```

Comment: How do you want to split a single string to an array? Any informations available?

Comment: Actually the particular string value to type cast is the column data present in objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessName"]

Comment: But a `DataRow[]` are multiple rows and a `Rows[i]["ProcessName"]` is a single string. So how to want to get multiple rows out of a single string. You haven't told us much.

Comment: Rows[i] we are incrementing this i in for loop above this statement,so each time it iterates its value increments.   for (int i = 0; i < objds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a variable of type `DataRow[]` called `drProcess` but have not yet created an array of DataRows in which to put any values. Instead you've tried to tell the compiler that the string you're retrieving is actually a DataRow, which it isn't.

It's possible that what you want to do is to create your array of DataRows, then create a DataRow object and assign it into the array. However, I'm suspicious that this isn't actually what you're trying to achieve. Note that `objds.Tables[0].Rows` is already a collection of DataRows. You can actually edit or use this collection yourself if you need.

Or if you're wanting to create a new collection of process names you might be better creating a `var processes = new List<string>()` then calling `process.Add(objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessName"].ToString())`.

It all depends what you want to do with this collection of process names afterwards.

Comment: from first two lines i think what you are trying to say is DataRow[] drProcess=new DataRow[];   drProcess=objds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessName"].ToString();        Hope so you are getting me else please explain where i am mistaken.

Comment: No, there you firstly created a new array of DataRows, and stored that in a variable called drProcess. drProcess is, in effect, just a box containing a pointer to this new array of DataRows. Then you are attempting to replace the contents of this box with a pointer to the string you're retrieving. This means that firstly there is no longer a pointer to the new DataRow array you created, and secondly that you're attempting to store a pointer to a string into a variable that can only contain a pointer to an array of DataRows.

Answer (score 0):

First, a  `DataRow` always belongs to a `DataTable`. To which table should these new `DataRow` belong? I will presume `objds.Tables[0]`.

I also assume that you have a string-column and you want to split every field in it to a `DataRow[]`, then we need to know the delimiter.

Presuming it is a comma:

```
DataRow[] drprocess = objds.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<string>("ProcessName").Split(',')
    .Select(name => {
        DataRow row = objds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        row.SetField("ProcessName", name);
        return row;
    })
    .ToArray();
```